# Admob in a recyclerview

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, admob

I'm trying to add an Admob banner in a recyclerview.

My problem is to initialize the Admob.

I have 2 views: the Adview and the list.xml. Adview has Admob xml banner on it.

**Adapter**

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v;
    if (viewType == ad) {
        ad_act = 1;
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.adview, parent, false);
    }
    else {
        ad_act = 0;
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);
    }
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}
```

I need to initialize the Admob, so I tried to add it in my main activity not in my adapter:

**Main Activity inside onCreate:**

```
ViewGroup content = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, content, true);

MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

but this gives me a null exception R.id.adView

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)'
>   on a null object reference

since I'm not adding the r.layout.adview in the main_activity. Any ideas how can I add it there?

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, the issue is that you're searching the Activity's layout for the AdView, and it can't be found there during onCreate. Just create your AdViews programmatically using their constructor in onCreate, and keep them in a list along with your data items that back the adapter.

If you're interested, we have a sample up for how to do this with the Native Express format, which can have the same size as a banner, but gives you the option of styling the ads yourself. It's easily adapted to banners, if you'd prefer those:

- [Native Express RecyclerView sample](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/blob/master/advanced/NativeExpressRecyclerViewExample)
- [Video tutorial for Native Express in a RecyclerView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZCZSeFTvyk&index=11&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIKX0pUJV3uqp6N3NeHwHh0c)

Comment: For update; Native Express Ads are deprecated. And Native Ads are not available for every developer for now.